# Generic Comparable type for compareTo

Tags: java, comparable, compareto

I have a method called `getMember` which may return any Comparable object, String, Integer etc.
I can't figure out what to use as type parameter so `compareTo` will work. Code below is not working

```
Comparable<? extends Comparable<?>> m1 = column.getMember(o1);
Comparable<? extends Comparable<?>> m2 = column.getMember(o2);

int compareTo = m1.compareTo(m2);
```

In case I wasn't clear, m1 and m2 will always be same type. Comparing without type parameters works fine, I just wanted to know what to put in <>

Comment: Assume that `getMember(o1)` returns a String and `getMember(o2)` returns an Integer (which is possible based on your description), it makes sense that you can't compare them...

Comment: @assylias it cannot happen. They will be always of same type

Comment: *You* may know that, but the compiler doesn't know that based on the types you declared `m1` and `m2` to be. It just knows that `m1` is a `Comparable` of some type and `m2` is a `Comparable` of some type that may or may not be the same type the `m1` is.

Comment: You should use parameterized type instead of unknow that is `Comparable<T extends Comparable<T>> m1 = column.getMember(o1);`. But I cannot say more with my current knowledge (or absence of knowledge) of how `getMember` method is declared, what it does, what its class does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need here is a [generic method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html). Whatever method this section of code is in must be generified. Here's my best shot, in absence of your source for the `getMember` method.

```
public <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void doSomethingTheOPWants() {
    ...
    T m1 = column.getMember(o1);
    T m2 = column.getMember(o2);
    int compareTo = m1.compareTo(m2);
}
```

With my current knowledge of the code, I don't think I can create a relevant/worthwhile test, so I'll leave that up to OP.